# IE7 float an unordered list

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HUcG/12/).. and render it in firefox and IE7 (or 6)

In firefox, it renders fine. but in IE7, the menu goes away (it should display at right)

Why it happens? and What's the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is just to leave it like this. IE7 does not support some CSS attributes. In this case, IE7 does not support `overflow:hidden;` and have some problems with `float:right;` . 
on your design, try to focus on IE8+ and other major browsers like Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. Trust me, working with a design that is supported by old browsers is a pain in the ...*

Comment: my website works fine on IE8+ and other modern browsers, unfortunately about 5% of my visitors use IE7 or 6 and my website should works for them..

Comment: use `if IE` to show certain things only for the browser specified.

for more info please take a look at this  [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Hint : try changing your HTML structure on IE7 or less only

Answer (score 0):

hi now used to css condition as like this

```
 <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        #container{
    direction: none;
}
    <![endif]-->
```

now i m testing in ie 7 apply this rule it's fine .